# Multidimensional Arrays Error inderoutofbounds

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm just learning to use multidimensional arrays in java.
I got an error when i try to create a matrix of 3x3 which values inputted by the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myMatrix 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double[][] matrixOne = new double[3][3];
        double[][] matrixTwo = new double[3][3];
        double[][] finalMatrix = new double[3][3];
        Scanner takeInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter values of matrix One");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;i<3;j++)
            {
                matrixOne[i][j] = takeInput.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Enter values of matrix Two");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;i<3;j++)
            {
                matrixTwo[i][j] = takeInput.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;i<3;j++)
            {
                finalMatrix[i][j] = matrixOne[i][j] + matrixTwo[i][j];
                System.out.print(finalMatrix[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

After inputting 4 numbers, i get an error that array index out of bounds.
Why's that?
Have i made any mistake in the program?

Comment: I would recommend using matrixOne.length instead of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int j=0;i<3;j++)
{
    matrixOne[i][j] = takeInput.nextDouble();
}
```

In this loop you're checking for `i<3` not `j<3` this would cause your error.

Answer (score 1):

Its only a small mistake. Your second "for" loop is using "j" as variable but checking "i" for condition

```
for(int j=0;i<3;j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the inner loops have the same issue:

for(int j=0;**i<3**;j++)

It should be j not i.

Change it to the following code:

for(int j=0;**j<3**;j++)